# Did Jesus ever tell jokes or use humor?

Tags: life-of-jesus, new-testament

The New Testament tells us that Jesus was an exceptional storyteller who used symbolism to spread the Word of God.

But did He ever use humor while telling stories? Or in His day-to-day life?

Did He ever use sarcasm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that telling Peter to go catch a fish and he would find a coin in its mouth to pay their temple tax was pretty funny.

Also, when asked if it is right to pay taxes to Caesar, asking them whose picture was on the coinage was pretty humorous.

However, consider that Jesus is the Word of God. The whole of the Old Testament is an expression of Jesus' character and nature, and it made frequent use of humor. My favorite was when Elijah asked the priests of Baal to shout louder because maybe their God was asleep. The second funniest thing was David pretending to be crazy and foaming at the mouth in order to save his skin from a hostile neigboring king.

Comment: Perhaps move this answer to the referenced duplicate question.